# Programmatically sort dhtmlxgrid in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dhtmlx

I want to sort dhtmlxgrid with data on the server side, I realized that there is a PHP library present [here](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__reference.html).

Is there a way I can achieve this in Ruby On Rails?

Comment: You could try here... https://dhtmlx.com/blog/tag/ruby-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

The logic for the server-side sorting in dhtmlxGrid is following:

- Cancel the client-side sorting;
- Clear the grid and load the data sorted on the server side;
- Set the position and direction of the marker in the grid header that shows sorting direction.

All these steps are performing on the client-side and are not independent of the using server-side.
Here you can find a tutorial:
[server-side sorting](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__dynamic_loading.html#step5sortdata)